# Continuity and differentiability (definitions)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, definition

I know that a function $f$ is continuous at $a \iff \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$. And that we define a function at an isolated point $b$ as continuous at $b$. Though, I've had trouble finding definitions for the following:

What do we usually define a function $f(x)=2x, x\in (-\infty,5]$ to be at $x=5$?

Is it continuous and differentiable at $x=5$?

If it is differentiable at $x=5$ then are all functions differentiable at isolated points too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More generally, think of an open neighborhood of a point (isolated or cluster) in the domain with respect to the topology (*induced* by the domain of $f$, i.e. the intersection of an open set with the domain.)  Then you'll find that at the definition of continuity at an isolated point is natural, and the differentiability also holds since the condition for $\delta > 0$ is *vacuumly satisfied*.

Answer (score 0):

GNU's comment is correct but it requires some familiarity with point-set topology. His comment is basically saying, "Yes because you can just use limits approach from the left".

Comment: So, just to make things clear, it is both continuous and differentiable at $x=5$ and a function is also differentiable at an isolated point (i.e. $f(x)=c$ for $x=d$ (single point only))?